# how to compress only files inside folder and not the folder java

Tags: java, android, zip, unzip

im using code to compress a folder containing files and subfolders, what i want is compressing the files directly and not its folder.
[image: zip files to test.zip]

when i open the zip file i find the folder and the files is inside that folder, like this

[image]

what i want is to find the files directly after opening the zip file, like this .

[image]

this the code im using :

```
 ZipUtils appZip = new ZipUtils();
  appZip.zipIt(new java.io.File("/sdcard/Alarms"), new java.io.File("/sdcard/DCIM/test.zip"));
```

class

```
public static class ZipUtils {

        private final List<java.io.File> fileList;

        private List<String> paths;

        public ZipUtils() {
            fileList = new ArrayList<>();
            paths = new ArrayList<>(25);
        }

        public void zipIt(java.io.File sourceFile, java.io.File zipFile) {
            if (sourceFile.isDirectory()) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                java.io.FileOutputStream fos = null;
                java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream zos = null;

                try {

                    // This ensures that the zipped files are placed
                    // into a folder, within the zip file
                    // which is the same as the one been zipped
                    String sourcePath = sourceFile.getParentFile().getPath();
                    generateFileList(sourceFile);

                    fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(zipFile);
                    zos = new java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream(fos);

                    System.out.println("Output to Zip : " + zipFile);
                    java.io.FileInputStream in = null;

                    for (java.io.File file : this.fileList) {
                        String path = file.getParent().trim();
                        path = path.substring(sourcePath.length());

                        if (path.startsWith(java.io.File.separator)) {
                            path = path.substring(1);
                        }

                        if (path.length() > 0) {
                            if (!paths.contains(path)) {
                                paths.add(path);
                                java.util.zip.ZipEntry ze = new java.util.zip.ZipEntry(path + "/");
                                zos.putNextEntry(ze);
                                zos.closeEntry();
                            }
                            path += "/";
                        }

                        String entryName = path + file.getName();
                        System.out.println("File Added : " + entryName);
                        java.util.zip.ZipEntry ze = new java.util.zip.ZipEntry(entryName);

                        zos.putNextEntry(ze);
                        try {
                            in = new java.io.FileInputStream(file);
                            int len;
                            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                            }
                        } finally {
                            in.close();
                        }
                    }

                    zos.closeEntry();
                    System.out.println("Folder successfully compressed");

                } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        zos.close();
                    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void generateFileList(java.io.File node) {
// add file only
            if (node.isFile()) {
                fileList.add(node);
            }
            if (node.isDirectory()) {
                java.io.File[] subNote = node.listFiles();
                for (java.io.File filename : subNote) {
                    generateFileList(filename);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

can some one help me ?

Comment: If you don't want the path in the entry name, then why do you explicitly add it here: `String entryName = path + file.getName();` Get rid of that and simply use `file.GetName()` insetad of `entryname` and it should work as you describe.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks brother for answer, i deleted what you told me and now i get inide the zip file (( just one file with folders and subfolders only )) what wrong ??